# Could not find 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, firebase-job-dispatcher

I am trying to add Firebase Job Dispatcher to my project, but I am unable to build because of this error:

> Gradle sync failed: Could not find
>   com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:[version]. Required by: project
>   :[module]

My `build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {url "https://clojars.org/repo/"}
}

dependencies {
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'

    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.5.2'

    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.2'

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'

    compile 'frankiesardo:icepick:3.2.0'
    provided 'frankiesardo:icepick-processor:3.2.0'

    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.0'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
}
```

Additionally, I have version 45 of the Google Repository and version 39 of Google Play Services installed via the SDK manager.

According to the [documentation on the firebase-jobdispatcher Github page](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android#getting-started), this should be the only thing I need to add the dependency. My project does not rely on GCM, so I'm not sure what is going on. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: It may be connection problem. Internet, proxy, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, Gradle could not resolve the dependency using Maven Central alone. Adding JCenter to my list of repositories fixed the issue:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()  // new
    mavenCentral()
    maven {url "https://clojars.org/repo/"}
}
```

Comment: Now jcenter is outdated, what should be done in this case.

Comment: @Nipul adding jcenter again works for me as dispatcher is not avail in mavencentral currently.

Comment: JCenter is shutting down.

Comment: @NipulSindwani by now you should probably not use the jobdispatcher and follow up with the WorkManager: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/